# Another word for "Ingredients"

Tags: single-word-requests

**Ingredients**—a list of neccessary items you combine (usually in cooking).

What about building an electronic circuit board, with all the LEDs, resistors, etc? "Ingredients" feels wrong—I don't want to eat the board.

What is a more general term for "ingredients"?

Example sentence—*"If you want to make x, these are the [ingredients] required."*

Comment: Parts is parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Components would fit your example and use case. Element would also work.

"If you want to make x, these are the *components* required."

"If you want to make x, these are the *elements* required."

> #### Component - Dictionary.com
>
> 1) A constituent part; element; ingredient.
>
> 2) A part of a mechanical or electrical system: *hi-fi components*.
>
> Source link: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/component

---

> #### Component - Merriam-Webster.com ###
>
> One of the parts of something (such as a system or mixture) : an important piece of something.
>
> Source link: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/component

---

> #### Element - OxfordDictionaries.com
>
> A part or aspect of something abstract, especially one that is essential or characteristic:
>
> “the death had all the elements of a great tabloid story”
>
> “there are four elements to the proposal”
>
> Source link:
>   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/element

---

> #### Element - TheFreeDictionary.com
>
> A fundamental, essential, or irreducible constituent of a composite entity.
>
> Source link: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/element

Answer (score 0):

Although present in prince's answer, but not exclusively mentioned is **constituent**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent)

> one of the parts that form something.